# RAID0 Local SSD on Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to use Local SSD for one of my applications, however the data is > 350GB, so I would need to use 2 of them.

[gce auto mounts](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/local-ssd) and formats the SSDs into `/mnt/disks/ssdx`, but is there any way I could get the VM to RAID0 the SSDs before mounting?

Would editing the Startup script in a new instance template be the right place for this?

PS: I'm very new to GCE but fairly competent with Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This documented fairly well in the [Local SSD documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd)

Navigate to

> Format and mount individual local SSD devices

Comment: Yes its easy for compute engine, but I was interested to know about how to do it in *container* engine where Google manages the VM for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do have a solution for this, you can use a DaemonSet [1][2] it's useful for deploying ongoing background tasks that you need to run on all or certain nodes.

Example: if you want to run a start-up script on node level. see below the example, the DaemonSet is used for several purpose:

```
kind: DaemonSet 
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 
metadata: 
name: startup-script 
labels: 
app: startup-script 
spec: 
template: 
metadata: 
labels: 
app: startup-script 
spec: 
hostPID: true 
containers: 
- name: startup-script 
image: gcr.io/google-containers/startup-script:v1 
imagePullPolicy: Always 
securityContext: 
privileged: true 
env: 
- name: STARTUP_SCRIPT 
value: | 
#! /bin/bash 
<YOUR COMMAND LINE> 
<YOUR COMMAND LINE> 
echo done
```

[1]https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/daemonset#creating_daemonsets 
[2]https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Comment: this is not an appropriate solution, nor does it answer the question